# Mutual words in files using hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I have been trying to execute some code that would allow me to 'only' list the words that exist in multiple files; what I have done so far was use the wordcount example and thanx to Chris White I managed to compile it. I tried reading here and there to get the code to work but all I am getting is a blank page with no data. the mapper is suppose to collect each word with its corresponding locations; the reducer is suppose to collect the common words any thoughts as to what might be the problem? the code is:

```
    package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {



    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
    {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

          private Text outvalue=new Text();
          private String filename = null;

        public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {
        if (filename == null) 
        {
          filename = ((FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
        }

        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
          word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
          outvalue.set(filename);
          output.collect(word, outvalue);
        }

        }
    }



    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
    {


        private Text src = new Text();
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {


        int sum = 0;
        //List<Text> list = new ArrayList<Text>(); 

            while (values.hasNext()) // I believe this would have all locations of the same word in different files?
            {

                sum += values.next().get();
                src =values.next().get();

            }
        output.collect(key, src);
            //while(values.hasNext()) 
            //{ 
                //Text value = values.next(); 
                //list.add(new Text(value)); 
                //System.out.println(value.toString());       
            //} 
            //System.out.println(values.toString()); 
            //for(Text value : list) 
            //{ 
                //System.out.println(value.toString()); 
            //} 


        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");
    conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    //conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
    JobClient.runJob(conf);

    }

}
```

Am I missing anything?
much obliged...
My Hadoop version : 0.20.203

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086818/wordcount-common-words-of-files is the original question

Answer (score 1):

First of all it seems you're using the old Hadoop API (mapred), and a word of advice would be to use the new Hadoop API (mapreduce) which is compatible with 0.20.203

In the new API, here is a wordcount that will work

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCount {
/**
 * The map class of WordCount.
 */
public static class TokenCounterMapper
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
/**
 * The reducer class of WordCount
 */
public static class TokenCounterReducer
    extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
/**
 * The main entry point.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Example Hadoop 0.20.1 WordCount");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenCounterMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TokenCounterReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

Then, we build this file and pack the result into a jar file:

```
mkdir classes
javac -classpath /path/to/hadoop-0.20.203/hadoop-0.20.203-core.jar:/path/to/hadoop-  0.20.203/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d classes WordCount.java && jar -cvf wordcount.jar -C classes/ .
```

Finally, we run the jar file in standalone mode of Hadoop

```
echo "hello world bye world" > /tmp/in/0.txt
echo "hello hadoop goodebye hadoop" > /tmp/in/1.txt
hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.packagename.WordCount /tmp/in /tmp/out
```

Comment: I suggested to use the new API because I've seen a lot of people who keep using the old API just because the official doc is still under the old API...

Comment: I understand the change thank you; however since I started learning on the old API I thought to master it and move up the ladder; and I understand one of the changes is the COntext object...Thank you ya...

Answer (score 1):

In the reducer, maintain a set of the values observed (the filenames emitted in the mapper), if after you consume all the values, this set size is 1, then the word is only used in one file.

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
{
    private TreeSet<Text> files = new TreeSet<Text>();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
    {
        files.clear();

        for (Text file : values)
        {
            if (!files.contains(value))
            {
                // make a copy of value as hadoop re-uses the object
                files.add(new Text(value));
            }
        }

        if (files.size() == 1) {
            output.collect(key, files.first());
        }

        files.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris; I made the changes you mentioned; I have also put replaced the (Text file: values) line with the (Text value: files) if I am right!? it compiles and everything but I am still ending up with a blank executable file...any ideas?

Comment: I believe the error can be in the mapper? from the log screen I see "Combine input records=0", "Reduce input records=0"

Comment: It didn't pay much attention to the mapper - what input format are you using? TextInputFormat emits <LongWritable, Text> doesn' it? Do you need to configure the StrinkTokenizer with a delimiter? Can you write  a unit test to test your String tokenizer logic?

Comment: I have just checked with the mapper; in the collector I have the word and outvalue. the outvalue actually does contain the file name. but when I try to output the word (the key) it shows empty string? can this be it?

Comment: btw I had this line "conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);" replaced with "conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);" can this be the reason; just assuming since the word keeps on showing blank/null...

Comment: Hey chris thank you for finding the time to help me out ya....I have decided to try another example...Big help you were thnx...